# FFmpeg problems with playing a stream

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, openwrt

I want to play a stream over network. While my server works I can't get it working receiving audio on client. It's router with openwrt installed and usb soundcard.

When i run
`ffmpeg -i "udp://@:5555" -f alsa hw:0`  i get a following error

```
[NULL @ 0x76b2b390] Requested output format 'alsa' is not a suitable output format
hw:0: Invalid argument
```

What's wrong with my command?
On router there is limited space. I hardly handled to install ffmpeg.

There is complete log  :

```
root@LEDE:/proc/asound# ffmpeg -i "udp://@:5555" -f alsa hw:0
ffmpeg version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (LEDE GCC 5.4.0 r3101-bce140e)
  configuration: --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=mips-openwrt-linux-musl- --arch=mips --target-os=linux --prefix=/usr --pkg-config=pkg-config --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-small --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-doc --disable-debug --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-dxva2 --disable-lzma --disable-vaapi --disable-vda --disable-vdpau --disable-outdevs --disable-altivec --disable-vsx --disable-power8 --disable-amd3dnow --disable-amd3dnowext --disable-mmx --disable-mmxext --disable-sse --disable-sse2 --disable-sse3 --disable-ssse3 --disable-sse4 --disable-sse42 --disable-avx --disable-xop --disable-fma3 --disable-fma4 --disable-avx2 --disable-aesni --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-armv6t2 --disable-inline-asm --disable-mipsdsp --disable-mipsdspr2 --disable-mipsfpu --disable-msa --disable-mmi --disable-fast-unaligned --disable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-yasm --enable-libopus --enable-decoder=libopus --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@:5555':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 384 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 384 kb/s
[NULL @ 0x76b2b390] Requested output format 'alsa' is not a suitable output format
hw:0: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Maybe you disabled the alsa muxer. Can only guess without the complete log from the ffmpeg command.

Comment: I added the log output

Answer (score 0):

Your `ffmpeg` was compiled with `--disable-outdevs` which disabled all output devices including ALSA.

You will need to re-compile by either omitting `--disable-outdevs`, or by adding `--enable-outdev=alsa`.